HttpClient showing network error "A connection attempt failed because the connect party did not properly respond"?
In my code, a HttpClient is making a request to identity server for token connect/token from UI controller, but I get an error

A connection attempt failed because the connect party did not properly respond

But the main issue is, I am able to access that identity server from the browser & I make the same request from XMLHttpRequest which is generating access_token.
Commonly above error message indicate that one server is not able connect with identity server, but when I am able to access through browser.
Can you tell me in which direction I should go further to debug, or what tools I can use?
as asked in comments , adding code snipet which is i am using in asp.net web site
 using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
 {
     PasswordTokenRequest passwordTokenRequest = new PasswordTokenRequest()
     {
         Address = authURL + "/connect/token",
         GrantType = "password",

         ClientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientId"],
         Scope = accessTokenScopes,
         UserName = model.UserName,
         Password = decriptedPassword

     };

     string sccesstok = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(passwordTokenRequest);
     Logging.WriteLog(sccesstok, Logging.LogMsgType.General);


     var identityServerResponse = client.RequestPasswordTokenAsync(passwordTokenRequest).Result;
     
     if(identityServerResponse.IsError)
     {
            string innerException = identityServerResponse.Exception.InnerException != null ? identityServerResponse.Exception.InnerException.ToString() : "";
    string allMsg = $"HttpStatusCode: {identityServerResponse.HttpStatusCode.ToString()};" +
       $"           HttpErrorReason: {identityServerResponse.HttpErrorReason};" +
       $"           Exception Message: {identityServerResponse.Exception.Message}; " +
       $"           Exception StackTrace: {identityServerResponse.Exception.StackTrace}; " +
       $"           InnerException: {innerException}";

    Logging.WriteLog(allMsg, Logging.LogMsgType.General);
     }
     }


At least at the few lins of failing code then we can see if there is something obviously wrong. Like using GET instead of POST or something like that you missed. The returned Http Error code would be helpful (if there is one) and the actually Exception type not just the text.

What’s the project type? That determines where the code runs, in browser or on server side. That matters a lot as the network settings are completely different.

@Ralf           i have added code.

@LexLi         it is asp.net website. code is running in window server but i have also tested on browser which is running on same server


ASP.NET 4.x or ASP.NET Core? With Blazor or not? 2) A tool like Wireshark might show you more details about the network error on the server itself. You still have a long way to go before asking a good enough question here for others to answer.

